# Importing content to XNA program using code?

Tags: xna

Is it possible that a XNA program able to import the resource (etc: image, sound) into the content of the program via code? For example, the user want to add an new image into the program, the XNA program will behave like the Window's Add File or Copy File. If possible WinForm shall avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
         OpenFileDialog f = new OpenFileDialog();
         f.Filter = "PNG files (*.png)|*.png|All files (*.*)|*.*";
         f.Title = "Import Image"; 
         DialogResult result = f.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.   
         string file = "";
         if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
         {
            file = f.FileName;
         }
         else //If cancels, handle here
         Application.Exit();
         using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
         {
             //Load the Texture here
             YourTexture = Texture2D.FromStream(GraphicsDevice, SourceStream);
         }
```

That uses a simple WinForms OpenDialog Window, but if you don't want winforms, you can make your own and use this part just to load.

```
       using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
       {
           //Load the Texture here
           YourTexture = Texture2D.FromStream(GraphicsDevice, SourceStream);
       }
```

You can save the Texture2D Back by doing

```
        using(Stream stream = File.Create(file)); 
        {
        texture.SaveAsPng(stream, texture.Width, texture.Height);
        }
```

Comment: How about saving into the Content file? Perhaps i need to create my own App's storage to save all imported files?

Comment: Well you already know the file path from the 'file' variale, so look at the documentation on `Texture2D.SaveAsPng` EDIT: Take a look at the changes I made